# Simultaneous evidence for $L\neq NL$ and $P\neq NP$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, big-picture, polynomial-time, logspace

We believe $L\neq NL$ and $P\neq NP$.

Is there any evidence which simultaneously imply $L\neq NL$ and $P\neq NP$?